# Two names points to the same object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, alias, object-reference

Consider the following example:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, lis: list):
        self.list = lis


lis = [1, 2, 3]
obj1 = Test(lis)
obj2 = Test(lis)

print(obj1 is obj2)
print(obj1.list is obj2.list)

obj1.list.reverse()
print(obj2.list)
```

Output :

```
False
True
[3, 2, 1]
```

**Explanation**:

I create 2 objects of the same class,and the "list" of each object is `[1, 2, 3]`. Testing if the names `obj1`,`obj2` are referencing the same object the answer is negative (False). But when I test if `obj1.list is obj2.list`, we get '`True`' as an answer.Thus when I reverse the list of the name `obj1`,the list is also reversed of the name `obj2`, because it is the same list for both names.

What I need is a way to reverse the list for `obj1`, but not for `obj2`. So I need to create a new list.

In the end,this will be the result:

```py
obj1.list.reverse()
print(obj2.list)
```

Expected output:

```py
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copy method` in Python returns a `shallow copy of a list`.
Shallow copy means that: any modification made in the new list won’t affect the original list.

For example:

```
lis1=['a','b','c']
print(lis1)
lis2=lis1
print(lis2)
lis1.pop()
print(lis1, lis2)
```

The output is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b'] ['a', 'b']
```

In this example, the `lis1` and `lis2` refer to the same address. Thus any changes in either of them will result in changes in the other as well.

We can solve this problem by using the `copy method` of list or by using the `copy module`.

For example:

```
lis1=['a','b','c']
print(lis1)
lis2=lis1.copy()
print(lis2)
lis1.pop()
print(lis1, lis2)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

In this example, the `lis2` is a copy of the `lis1` stored at a different address hence when we change `lis1` no change is seen in `lis2`.

Similarly copy module can be used too. For example:

```
import copy

lis1=['a','b','c']
print(lis1)
lis2=copy.copy(lis1)
print(lis2)
lis1.pop()
print("list1=",lis1,"list2=", lis2)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
list1= ['a', 'b'] list2= ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Similarly your problem can be solved using `copy method`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, lis: list):
        self.list = lis

lis = [1, 2, 3]
obj1 = Test(lis)
obj2 = Test(lis)
obj2new=obj2.list.copy()

print(obj1 is obj2)
print(obj1.list is obj2.list)

obj1.list.reverse()
print(obj2new)
```

Now, the desired output is returned:

```
False
True
[1, 2, 3]
```

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Thank you,it is really usefull.But i can't accept 2 answers :(

Comment: So just accept mine, haha! Just kidding! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: if u change the "True" to "False" in the output i will :P

Comment: oh! well now that you've accepted my answer, do I still need to?:D

Comment: I think it is just a small mistake,after your modification i think the following line prints "False" : ```print(obj1.list is obj2.list)```

Answer (score 3):

You are storing the same reference to list in `self.list`, which you can avoid by making a copy:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, lis: list):
        self.list = lis[:]
```

Consider it as a pointer. So, when you modify one, the other which is pointing to the same value also changes.

Comment: This worked perfectly.I can't accept your answer yet,due to time restrictions,but i will in 10 minutes.Thank you :)

Comment: Reader beware: this creates a shallow copy. If the list is nested, then the nested elements will not be copied. The OP here is using flat lists so a shallow copy is fine, but for nested lists, it's probably best to use `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: @jakub: it's probably not worth to use `deepcopy` for a flat list. Hence, suggested a shallow one.